# Axis2 generates Skeleton only for one port, but I have 2 ports

Tags: apache-axis, wsdl2java

I have 2 ports in my WSDL:

```
<wsdl:portType name="Interface1">
<wsdl:portType name="Interface2">
```

I call

```
wsdl2java  -g -o result -p  "com.foo" -ss -ssi -ap -g -uri  MyService.wsdl
```

After it I can find only "Interface1SkeletonInterface.java" in my "com/foo" folder.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

wsdl2java has a [command-line option](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html#cmdref) `-pn` or `--port-name` to specify which port to generate code for. If not specified, the default is to generate code for the first listed port.

The [ant task](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html#antref) has an equivalent option `portName`.

Comment: Yes, but the -ap/--all-ports option is supposed to make wsdl2java generate all the ports, not just one.